# cucumber-rails ignores path.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I'm slowly digging into my first rails app with Cucumber. I'm building tables and now want to edit the table ReferenceCommodities. This is using DanielKehoe's rails3-cucumber-devise template found on github. Here is my feature:

Feature: I want to edit these Reference Commodities so that they can be correct for users.

```
Scenario Outline: Edit values
Given I am logged in

Given there are Reference Commodities

| Type       | Commodity | Language |
| government | corn   | en |
| government | maize  | sz |


Scenario: Edit Reference Commodities
When I go to the Reference Commodities home page
Then I should see this reference commodity

| Type       | Commodity | Language |
| government | corn   | en |
| government | maize  | sz |

And I click on "edit"

Then I should see the edit page with this reference commodity
| type      | "government" |
| commodity | "corn"       |
| language  | "en"         |

And I fill in the following:
| type      | "private" |
| commodity | "corn"       |
| language  | "en"         |

Then it should edit this Reference Commodity
```

Here is my step_definition. Note that DanielKehoe's starter already has cucumber tests for the user and my log in steps point to those. They pass cucumber's tests.

```
Given /^I am logged into$/ do
  # table is a Cucumber::Ast::Table
  sign_up valid_user
end

Given /^there are Reference Commodities$/ do |table|
  # table is a Cucumber::Ast::Table
  @reference_commodities = ReferenceCommodity.create!(table.rows_hash)
end

When /^I go to the Reference Commodities home page$/ do
  visit('/reference_commodities/index')
   save_and_open_page
end

Then /^I should see this reference commodity$/ do |table|
  # table is a Cucumber::Ast::Table
  page.should have_content @reference_commodities[:commodity]
end
```

What's failing is the going to the index where you see the 'save_and_open_page in capybara. It's going to a dummy page in the reference_commodities#show which isn't really mapped out in the paths.rb. My routes file has reference_commodities as a resource. I do have a new and create action in an earlier feature that seem to pass cucumber tests. The create action does have a redirect_to(@reference_commodities ...options) but it' seems to be ignoring what I set in paths.rb?

Here is the salient portion of my paths.rb:

```
def path_to(page_name)
 case page_name

   when /the Reference Commodities home page/ 
   '/reference_commodities/index'
end
```

What am I overlooking for it to go to this path? thanx, sam

Comment: Did you know that the paths.rb has been removed from cucumber-rails? For reasons divined in this discussion: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/issues/174

So I don't think you need the paths.rb here. The visit call you make should be the URL that you want to call, so I expect that /index is wrong.